# Binding Checkbox to td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently developing a web application that populates a table (using the dynatable jquery plugin) using json.

One of my needs is to bind a checkbox to a particular column (email) and to be able to retrieve a list of selected addresses and convert them into a comma separated string.

This is my first time i'm actively writing some javascript and every attempt i've currently made has failed miserably.

I create the checkbox using :

```
$(".sth:nth-child(5)").prepend("<input type='checkbox' name='mailcheck' id='cbe'> ");
```

where sth is a class assigned to every td.

but have no idea how to proceed, i've tried creating an onclick event but i do not know how to bind the event to the control.

Anyone got some ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is an example of a td + checkbox (again, generated through dynatable and javascript)

```
 <td class="sth" style="text-align: left;" abp="61"><input name="mailcheck" id="cbe" onclick="ocEvent()" type="checkbox" abp="62"> am.marzano@gmail.com</td>
```

Comment: its better to share your html as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding `checkbox` dynamically to the `table` you can attach `clickevent` to it as below:

While you prepend add one more property called `class` to `checkbox`

```
$(".sth:nth-child(5)").prepend('<input type="checkbox" class="chkadd" name="mailcheck" id="cbe">');
```

Adding `change` event to dynamically added `checkbox`

```
$(document).on('change','.chkadd',function(){
          //do required stuffs here
});
```

instead of `$(document)` you can use `$('#yourTableID')`

**UPDATE**

To get `emailAddress` of each row where you have added `checkbox` you can do it as below:

Assuming that you have `emailAddress` placed in 3rd column

```
$(document).on('change','.chkadd',function(){
       var email =  $(this).parent().closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
});
```

change number inside `nth-child(3)` based on the column

Comment: This seems nice, but how can i get the email address string?

Comment: Anytime!! Happy coding.. :)

Comment: This solution seems to work but the only problem is the fact that anytime i sort the table the checkboxes go away. I do the prepend in the .ajaxComplete right now

This is the url i get after sorting Index.html?sorts[email]=-1

Comment: You need to call the `prepend` during sorting too then!! Hope you are doing that!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, id's must be unique. therefore since you append multiple instances of the checkbox, you better use a class instead of the ID.

Also, you could create a template checkbox and append a copy of it into the TD

```js
var selected_emails = "";
$(function() {
  //create a template checkbox
  var $checkBox = $("<input type='checkbox' class='cbe'/>");
  //append a click handler to it
  $checkBox.on("click", getList);
  //append a copy of the checkbox to each 5th td
  //the booleans mean copy with the attached events
  $("#myTable tr td:nth-child(5)").prepend($checkBox.clone(true, true));

});

//this function will run each time a checkbox is clicked
function getList() {
  //get a list of all TD, use filter to keep only those that have
  //a checked checkbox in them, then use map and get to retrieve the 
  //text inside that TD, and join the texts into one comma separated string
  selected_emails = $("#myTable tr td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(".cbe:checked").length > 0;
  }).map(function() {
    return $(this).parent().text().replace(/[\n ]/g, "");
  }).get().join(",");

 $("#Emails").text(selected_emails);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>email_1@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>email_2@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>email_3@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>email_4@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>email_5@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>email_6@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>email_7@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="Emails"></div>
```